# No publication in MS

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-admissions

I completed my MS-by research (thesis) in US in EE (well-renowned university and advisors)  and unfortunately, I do not have any papers published.

At present, I am leading (read it as pitch idea, receive funding, setup lab, perform research) an international research collaboration in Industry. I have conceived this idea that has the potential to solve long-standing problems in this particular industry. What is that I am doing differently is application of this concept in this sector of Industry ( and of course solving the problem).

The only thing that is keeping me away from applying for P.hD. program is that I do not have a publication.

Is there a suggestion what I must do in the current research? Advisors under whom I want to work for PhD is top 5 in universities.

Comment: If you're already leading an international research collaboratin in industry, are you sure you want / need a PhD? It sounds like you're doing something pretty cool right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the lack of publications will be much of a barrier, but I also think you need more realistic goals. Top five US universities is a pretty small (minuscule) cross section of what is available. The total number of positions in any given year is small and the demand is gigantic.

Any application to a doctoral program in the US will be judged on a variety of things, including letters of recommendation, rather than on any single criterion. The admissions committee wants to be able to make a fairly solid prediction that each candidate is likely to be a success. Given your background as you state it, you can probably get admitted somewhere. But your chances at only those top five places is pretty tiny.

I suggest that you apply to a range of R1 universities, including those if you like. Maybe you get lucky but you will be more likely to find something suitable if you cast a wider net. Look at the top fifty, say, and see what they offer. some of the State University programs, for example, are larger and have more slots available, due to a large faculty. But also look for professors with working groups in and area of interest. The right advisor can make all the difference.

And, if you have the time, there is no reason you can't still publish as an independent researcher.